# Cannot comment on other's question when new but can only "answer" - Misleading to other users

Tags: discussion, comments

I just joined and I may have a question for the original poster but I have to use "Post Your Answer" in order to ask it because I am less than 50 points.  This is misleading to other users.  I would like to contribute but don't want to be a bother to other users.

Would it be possible to allow new users to add comments on other user's questions or is there a good reason like preventing spam?

Comment: There are millions of questions that might not need clarification. Try answering one or two of those first.

Comment: I did read the faq and did a quick search for possible duplicate questions first (obviously I did a lousy job of phrasing the search or I would have found many duplicates) maybe someone should add this FAQ to the faq.  Also adding a clarification to the faq on how easy it is to gain reputation would be a good idea too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reason like preventing spam.

**Solution:** Earn 50 reputation points.  This can easily be done with a single, well-written answer to someone's question.